# How to know when cocoahttpserver has started

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoahttpserver

Does it send a notification that it has started that can be listed for, or is there a delegate protocol to implement?

I can't find the documentation on the [Google code page](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `- (BOOL)start:(NSError **)errPtr` does return true when the server is started, false otherwise (any error will be available at `errPtr` pointer). Further, the server publishes bonjour announcement upon successful startup.